# Pandas index interpolation filling in missing values after the last data point

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

Having a data frame with missing values at the end of a column, f.e.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan,1,2,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan]}, index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

     a
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  NaN
4  NaN
5  5.0
6  NaN
7  NaN
```

Using 'index' interpolation method:

```
df.interpolate(method='index')
```

Returns the data frame with the last missing values forward filled:

```
     a
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  3.0
4  4.0
5  5.0
6  5.0
7  5.0
```

Is there a way to turn off that behaviour and leave the last missing values:

```
     a
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  3.0
4  4.0
5  5.0
6  NaN
7  NaN
```

Comment: you can use the `limit`  argument.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need new parameter `limit_direction` in `0.23.0+`, check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#dataframe-interpolate-has-gained-the-limit-area-kwarg):

```
df = df.interpolate(method='index', limit=1, limit_direction='backward')
print (df)
     a
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  3.0
4  4.0
5  5.0
6  NaN
7  NaN
```

EDIT: If want replace `NaN`s only inside add parameter `limit_area`:

```
df = df.interpolate(method='index',limit_area='inside')
print (df)
     a
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  3.0
4  4.0
5  5.0
6  NaN
7  NaN
```

Comment: There can be any number of values between the data points, modified the example in the question.

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński - Waht about change `limit=1` to `limit=len(df)` ?

Comment: NaN can also be in the beginning of the data frame, modified the example again.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that the last NaNs(one or more) should be remained?
How about this. 
Find the last valid arg index and split and interpolate and append.

```
valargmax=np.max(np.where((df.isnull().eq(False).values==True).flatten()==True))
r = df[0:(valargmax+1)].interpolate(method='index').append(df[(valargmax+1):])
print(r)
```

Comment: It is a good solution if for some reason it is not possible to use pandas 0.23.0 where `limit_area` is not present. I would expect that the solution using `limit_area` parameter might have a better performance?